# How do I determine an appropriate sample size for my experiment?

Tags: sample-size, small-sample

I want to do an experiment at my company's recruiting events to see if giving attendees some of our products has a measurable impact on how many people actually apply for positions and/or get hired.

I'm a statistics novice. How do I figure out what kind of sample size I would need? Also, if my company has historical data about our recruiting events' "success" rate, can I use that in place of a control group?

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour]. A control group should be not giving things away, but you can you the data from the past incentives to see if the new incentives have a difference.  Your sample size will be dependent on the level of resolution that you are hoping to provide to your company.